# The BaseEntity used @MappedSuperclass And @IdClass. WARN HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```
@MappedSuperclass

@IdClass(BasePK.class)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private Long userId;

@Id
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private Long itemId;

private String a;

... other 

}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BasePk implements Serializable{

private Long userId;

private Long itemId;
}


@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class MoreEntity extends BaseEntity{


}
```

When application start ：
"WARN  o.h.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext   : HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field MoreEntity_#userId. this may or may not indicate a problem with the static metamodel". AND 
"WARN  o.h.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext   : HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field MoreEntity_#itemId. this may or may not indicate a problem with the static metamodel".

AND this WARN would appears twice!!!

## environment

```
<spring.boot.version>2.2.2.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
<spring.data.jpa.version>2.1.5.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
```

Comment: Not sure what question you are asking. Can you provide more details and perhaps a prose description of the problem?

Comment: In this application I used multiple data sources！

Comment: @weizhang, I have the exact same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @chaserb No solution was found. If you don't want a warning, you need to write a separate primary key for each entity class instead of inheriting abstract classes.